# ChangeAll command in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there a VS Code's ChangeAll command (Ctrl+F2) in Visual Studio? If not, is it a planned feature to implemented also in Visual Studio. If not, how hard will be to create a plugin to support this feature.

Comment: Is it the same as Refactoring - Rename?

Comment: @SergeyVlasov No, rename allows you to change one symbol at once across the solution. ChangeAll is for multi-cursor editing (not exactly, but similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqG2yve5ack).

Comment: For multi-cursor editing there is https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.MultiEditMode

Comment: @SergeyVlasov But I would like the ChangeAll feature. AFAIK here you have to create the cursors manually.